# Rutas relativas y absolutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rutas

El problema consiste en que cuando las rutas o directorios se extienden mass alla del directorio raiz, hay funcionalidades que no las reconoce. Adjunto archivo de rutas.

En el caso de esta ruta, me toma el estilo de Css, pero no los archivos Js donde tengo una tabla dinamica:

```
Route::get('/pacientes/listado', 'PersonaController@showTablePacientes')->name('listadoPacientes');
```

Pero en este caso me toma los archivos CSS y el JS

```
Route::get('/pacientes/', 'PersonaController@showTablePacientes')->name('listadoPacientes');
```

Estaria tendiendo problema con la declaracion rutas alternativas y absolutas.

Todos los archivos se encuentran dentro de la carpeta public/style_template y las rutas para que me funcionen son todas absolutas.

```
  <link href={{asset("styles_template/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")}} rel="stylesheet">
```

Esta ruta se encuentra en App/public/styles_template

De que manera se representan en Laravel las relativas para acceder desde todo el proyecto?

Saludos.

Comment: La carpeta `styles_template` esta dentro de la carpeta `App`?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias souciones, sin embargo, mostraré dos de las que ofrece y sugiere Laravel, en caso que no se puedan mover los archivos:

1. Copiar el archivo al directorio público deseado por medio de Laravel Mix:

   ```
   mix.copy('node_modules/foo/bar.css', 'public/css/bar.css');
   ```

   Ver documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#copying-files-and-directories
2. Combinar el archivo junto con otros de su mismo tipo (CSS o JS):

   ```
   mix.styles([
       'public/css/vendor/normalize.css',
       'public/css/vendor/videojs.css'
   ], 'public/css/all.css');
   ```

   Ver documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#plain-css

Dependiendo lo que quieras hacer, pueden existir otras opciones, pero estas serían las más adecuadas, asumiendo que no se pueden mover los archivos, y que permitan actualizar sus versiones.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede poner la ruta de base, a mi me funciona con poner {{ url('/') }} en el llamado de los links / imagenes etc del estilo

```
<script src="{{ url('/') }}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Eso hace que no importa cuandos / tengas en tu ruta, siempre los toma desde la base